# Issue of bars being of equal height in Pandas matplotlib

Tags: data-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis, eda

What could be the issue here, all bars are of equal height?
[bar plot in plt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYEfH.png)

[data used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/si66v.png)

Am doing an analysis of quantity of products sold in each City and plotting through plt.bar, why are the bars of equal height? I will appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Please don't post images for text contents. You should take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help people help you.